# Android: Implementing progressbar and "loading..." for Endless List like Android Market

Tags: android, android-listview

Taking inspiration from Android Market, i have implemented a Endless List which loads more data from the server when we reach the end of the List.

Now, i need to implement the progressbar & "Loading.." text as shown[image]

Sample code to take inspiration from would be great.

Comment: I am stuck in same can anyone help..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28122304/endless-scrolling-listview-not-working

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution that also makes it easy to show a loading view in the end of the ListView while it's loading.

You can see the classes here:

https://github.com/CyberEagle/OpenProjects/blob/master/android-projects/widgets/src/main/java/br/com/cybereagle/androidwidgets/helper/ListViewWithLoadingIndicatorHelper.java
- Helper to make it possible to use the features without extending from SimpleListViewWithLoadingIndicator.

https://github.com/CyberEagle/OpenProjects/blob/master/android-projects/widgets/src/main/java/br/com/cybereagle/androidwidgets/listener/EndlessScrollListener.java
- Listener that starts loading data when the user is about to reach the bottom of the ListView.

https://github.com/CyberEagle/OpenProjects/blob/master/android-projects/widgets/src/main/java/br/com/cybereagle/androidwidgets/view/SimpleListViewWithLoadingIndicator.java
- The EndlessListView. You can use this class directly or extend from it.

Comment: Can you add some example about how to use it?

Comment: need help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28122304/endless-scrolling-listview-not-working

Answer (score 3):

Add an [onScrollListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html) to the ListView. When the user scrolls, check if the ListView is nearing its end. If yes, then fetch more data. As an example :

```
public abstract class LazyLoader implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {

    private static final int DEFAULT_THRESHOLD = 10 ;

    private boolean loading = true  ;
    private int previousTotal = 0 ;
    private int threshold = DEFAULT_THRESHOLD ;

    public LazyLoader() {}

    public LazyLoader(int threshold) {
        this.threshold = threshold;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                         int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if(loading) {
            if(totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                // the loading has finished
                loading = false ;
                previousTotal = totalItemCount ;
            }
        }

        // check if the List needs more data
        if(!loading && ((firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount ) >= (totalItemCount - threshold))) {
            loading = true ;

            // List needs more data. Go fetch !!
            loadMore(view, firstVisibleItem,
                    visibleItemCount, totalItemCount);
        }
    }

    // Called when the user is nearing the end of the ListView
    // and the ListView is ready to add more items.
    public abstract void loadMore(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                                  int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount);
}
```

Activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

            listView.setOnScrollListener(new LazyLoader() {
                @Override
                public void loadMore(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                    // Fetch your data here !!!
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

You can find the complete implementation [at this link](http://androidcocktail.blogspot.in/2016/05/lazily-loaded-listview-in-android.html)

Answer (score 1):

The other answers here refer to outdated, unmaintained solutions. This article, however, seems to be kept up-to-date:
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView

There's too much there to put it all in a SO answer, but here's some important bits as of the time I'm writing this answer:

> Implementing endless pagination for `RecyclerView` requires the following steps:
>
> 1. Copy over the [EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener.java](https://gist.github.com/nesquena/d09dc68ff07e845cc622) into your application.
> 2. Call `addOnScrollListener(...)` on a `RecyclerView` to enable endless pagination. Pass in an instance of `EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener` and implement the `onLoadMore` which fires whenever a new page needs to be loaded to fill up the list.
> 3. Inside the aforementioned `onLoadMore` method, load additional items into the adapter either by sending out a network request or by loading from another source.
>
> To start handling the scroll events for steps 2 and 3, we need to use the `addOnScrollListener()` method in our `Activity` or `Fragment` and pass in the instance of the `EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener` with the layout manager as shown below:
>
> ```java
> public class MainActivity extends Activity {
>     // Store a member variable for the listener
>     private EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener scrollListener;
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>        // Configure the RecyclerView
>        RecyclerView rvItems = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvContacts);
>        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
>        rvItems.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
>        // Retain an instance so that you can call `resetState()` for fresh searches
>        scrollListener = new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(linearLayoutManager) {
>            @Override
>            public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view) {
>                // Triggered only when new data needs to be appended to the list
>                // Add whatever code is needed to append new items to the bottom of the list
>                loadNextDataFromApi(page);
>            }
>       };
>       // Adds the scroll listener to RecyclerView
>       rvItems.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
>   }
>
>   // Append the next page of data into the adapter
>   // This method probably sends out a network request and appends new data items to your adapter. 
>   public void loadNextDataFromApi(int offset) {
>       // Send an API request to retrieve appropriate paginated data 
>       //  --> Send the request including an offset value (i.e `page`) as a query parameter.
>       //  --> Deserialize and construct new model objects from the API response
>       //  --> Append the new data objects to the existing set of items inside the array of items
>       //  --> Notify the adapter of the new items made with `notifyItemRangeInserted()`
>   }
> }
> ```