# How add additional list to adapters

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have a ListView with separate headers.like.."Today events" is header and below of that it has list."Tomorrow events" is header and below of that it has some list.These two adapters in a single Listview.My problem is,in Each adapter have more than 20 items but it should display 20 items and when list scroll to 20 th item the remaining list should be displayed. How can i solve this.

Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [CommonsWare's `EndlessAdapter`](http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless), or at this [Endless Scrolling ListView in Android](http://benjii.me/2010/08/endless-scrolling-listview-in-android/).

Also, there have been several similar questions already on stackoverflow, so you could do a search prior to asking the question:

- [Android Endless List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080811/android-endless-list)
- [Endless List like Android Market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667064/android-implementing-endless-list-like-android-market)