# Android: not list all the item at once

Tags: android, mysql

When I browse some news apps, I see that the apps first show let's say 20 rows of news first, when I slide to the few last news, it loads 20 more news.
What is that technique called?
Is there any example or tutorial on that topics if I want to build a similar apps that get data from mysql?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some examples/thread that go over the same topic:

[Android: Implementing Endless List like Android Market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667064/android-implementing-endless-list-like-android-market)

[Dynamically load more items to the listview](http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-dynamicaly-load-more-items-to-the-listview-never-ending-list/)

[Android Endless List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080811/android-endless-list)