# Get whole sqlite records in android

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

How can I get all records without using a loop.Loop is not a good way to get 1000+ records.

For example:

```
public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
            // Adding contact to list
            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return contactList;
```

But this is not a best way to do so.Think you have 5000+ record.How much time does it take to complete this task!

How do you think ?

Regards,

Comment: use CursorAdapter for your ListView (instead ArrayAdapter) and do not load data to POJO ... than list should be quicker(a lot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Cursor` itself represents the "list" of items. That's why I have asked you what do you need to do with the data after retrieving from database...

If you only need to splash it on a `ListView`, then use `CursorAdapter`.
And even if you need to parse the "list" and send some items on the network or something other than displaying in a `ListView`, you still don't need an actual list. Just extract the items you need directly from the `Cursor` and send them away.

With the drawback of repeating myself, I should point out again: it really depends on what you want to do with the data.

Comment: I have no problem with displaying the data.I want a solution that users can see all the data(with paging or something else)

Comment: Like I already said above, use a CursorAdapter.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from table;
```

thats all...

in Android:

```
Cursor cursor = database.query(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_YOURTABLE,
    allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
```

I think a clearer way to iterate over the result:

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
  Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
        contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
        // Adding contact to list
        contactList.add(contact);
}
```

Comment: I know this but I don't know how can I handle this.After this line you have to add all the records into a List with a loop.I do not want to use a loop for 1000+ records duo to the performance

Comment: puhhh. good question. I dont think so...

Comment: thats why you got downvote @StefanBe

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the data. That's why you got -4 votes on the question, because you don't specify anything...

Comment: @BaZinga: It was an easy answer for an easy question. I see no reason for the downvote...

Comment: even if you use that query you have to iterate the loop to get the data from the cursor. and i dont think thats possible.

Comment: You must iterate all the results or querry row by row, but that's far away from being a performance design.

Comment: I have edited my question with more details

Comment: please take a look to my edited answer. I think thats a much clearer way to iterate over the result...

Comment: Thanks for you edit but does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to avoid loading thousands of records is to load less.
(You won't be able to fit thousands of entries onto the screen anyway.)

You probably want to implement some form of [lazy loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696530/android-listview-lazy-loading) for your list.

Comment: Good idea but how can I provide paging in a listview or something else to load step by step the data ?