# Retrieve data from Firebase gradually

Tags: java, android, mobile, cloud, firebase

I have a ListView that initially displays the last 10 items from Firebase. I want to display 10 more items whenever the user reaches the top of the list. How can I do that? Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicated in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667064/android-implementing-progressbar-and-loading-for-endless-list-like-android

Comment: This is a sample where Kato implemented this on AngularFire. The same approach could work on Android: https://gist.github.com/katowulf/0e14f81e2a10f75e3fcb