# How to reach bottom of listview, load more items

Tags: android, events, listview, scroll

When I reach the bottom of my ListView (Scroll down until the end), how do I load more items? 
Here is my class (maybe it will help)

```
public class ListFood extends Activity {

    int userid;
    String cat;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.list_food);

      ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
      TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
      Webservice ws = new Webservice();
      List<Afood> list = new ArrayList<Afood>();
      int i;

      Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
      userid = bundle.getInt("userid");
      cat = bundle.getString("cat");

      list = ws.getFoodFromCat(cat);
      String [] food = new String [list.size()];

      for(i=0;i<list.size();i++)
      {
        food[i] = list.get(i).name;  
      }

      if(cat.equalsIgnoreCase("FastFood"))
          tv.setText("Fast Food");
      else
          tv.setText(cat);

      lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list, food));     

      lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

      lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
          // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
      });
    }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Endless List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080811/android-endless-list)

Comment: I search it before i post this but couldn´t find it. Thanks 4 the tip, gonna go check it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the answer that @jleedev provided, you can also use my [`EndlessAdapter`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless) for this.