# need to trigger event when scroll ends

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I will list 10 files in list view. When user scroll ends, i will fetch other 10 files and append to existing list. This should occur recursively. Please guide how to do it.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Please see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You will find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731034/reach-bottom-of-listview-load-more-items) or you can look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080811/android-endless-list). This should solve your problem if you're willing to use libraries