# Make a "pull up to get more" for a list on the Android

Tags: android, android-widget

I just successfully used the Pull To Refresh by johannilsson  in order to pull down a list to update it.  Now I am trying to make basically the same concept to pull **up** a list  from the bottom in order to trigger getting more items from the server (The server I am calling returns a limited amount of items each time).  I thought it would be a simple inversion but after two days of trying to invert what the pull down does I am ready to pull *out* my hair.  Has anyone ever done something like this that they could point me to?

Comment: Doesn't http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080811/android-endless-list do what you want?

Comment: That's pretty close.  But it doesn't have the same behavior as "pull-to-refresh"  I guess the part I'm having difficulty with is the animation that triggers the event, not so much the event itself.  I need my client to be able to choose to load more, not just automatically load more when the end of the list is reached.

Comment: So, a gesture detect? Sorry, trying to wrap my head around the exact difference you're looking for? or detect when the attempt to scroll occurs when the list was already at the bottom?

Comment: So in the "pull down to refresh" effect the client can pull the list down from the top and there the option to release to refresh.  I used the [PulltoRefresh](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh) by johannilsson to achieve this in my own list. The Android Twitter app also displays this behavior.  What I need is this same concept, but at the end of the list of items.  I want to pull the list **up** and the release to trigger getting more items.  Is that more clear?