# Android ListView - detect when footer is visible

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Endless List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080811/android-endless-list)

I have a list.  When it scrolls to the bottom of the list, it should automatically load more rows. For example, I have a list of 10 rows, we scroll to the bottom and it loads 10 more rows giving a total of 20. I have a footer row at the bottom.  How can I detect when the footerrow is visible to the user?

Comment: I think this is a repeat question

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080811/android-endless-list][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080811/android-endless-list

Comment: how did you find that post? While writing my post I looked at all the suggested posts and that one was not on the list.

Comment: Google'd android detect bottom of list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement [OnScrollListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080811/android-endless-list) and check to see if the footer is visible and load items accordingly.