# To implement paging in listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, paging

Actually i have a list view containing 30 items.i want to implement paging ie to have two buttons as next & previous so that when i click next it displays some 5 items and so on.

Please provide me with sample code

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to implement an `OnScrollListener` and make changes (like adding items, etc.) to the `ListAdapter` at a convenient state in its onScroll method.

Adding items when the user scrolls to the end of the list.[**Click here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080811/android-endless-list)

Comment: have you tired ? that is also good for first time display performance.

Answer (score 0):

You could also add a footer element (Load more...).

To do this you have to:

```
View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_load_more, null);
myList.addFooterView(footer);
```

You could also load more items when listview is at the end, like: http://benjii.me/2010/08/endless-scrolling-listview-in-android/

Hope this helps...

Comment: i dont want to add items...i just want that at one time only 5 items should be displayed and when i click next another set of item is displayed.....kindly provide some sample code...i just need previous and next button functionality in a listview

Comment: So... you only have to refresh the list array adapter and call method notifydatasetchanged :)

Comment: By just refreshing array adapter is not working. On scroll up next records to be shown and on scroll down previous records to be shown. I tried everything but its not working. Any body knows how to do that? thanks

Answer (score 0):

i did something like this. You can also try. Its working nice

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    final int action = ev.getAction();
    if ((action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) && (mTouchState != TOUCH_STATE_REST)) {
        //here i handled continous move
        scrolltwice = true;
        return true;
    }

    final float x = ev.getX();
    final float y = ev.getY();
    switch(action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

        final int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(x - mLastMotionX);
        yDiff = (int) (y - mLastMotionY);
        final int ydif = (int) Math.abs(y - mLastMotionY);

        final int touchSlop = mTouchSlop;
        boolean xMoved = xDiff > touchSlop;
        boolean yMoved = ydif > touchSlop;
        if (xMoved || yMoved) {
            if (yMoved) {                   
                mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_SCROLLING;
            }
        }
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

        if (!mScroller.isFinished()) {
            mScroller.abortAnimation();
        }
        // Remember location of down touch
        mLastMotionX = x;
        mLastMotionY = y;           
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

        final int myDiff = (int) (y - mLastMotionY);

        if(mTouchState == TOUCH_STATE_SCROLLING){
            scrolltwice = false;
            if(!scrolltwice){
            Log.d("DB", " ACTION_UP fetch new records ");
                FetchRecords rec = new FetchRecords();
                rec.execute();  
                if(yDiff < 0){ // fetching next slot of records
                    nextRecordId = nextRecordId + previousTotal;
                    if(nextRecordId > totalRowCount){
                        nextRecordId = nextRecordId - previousTotal;
                    }
                }else if(yDiff > 0){ // fetching previous slot of records
                    nextRecordId = nextRecordId - previousTotal;
                    if(nextRecordId < 1){
                        nextRecordId = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        scrolltwice = false;
        mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_REST;
        break;
    }
    return false;

}

      //implement ontouch listener if the view is list pass it onTouchEvent
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(v.equals(objListView))
        onTouchEvent(event);
    return false;
}
```