# Fetching data from a web service on scroll and adding it to a listview.

Tags: android, xml, dynamic, adapter

This thing has been a cause of concern for me for the last week or so. I have a web service from which I can fetch xml data and parse it into string arrays. I want to fetch data from the web service dynamically on scroll and the string arrays to an adapter so that I can present them dynamically. I need some help for this one. Kindly help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080811/android-endless-list.

Answer (score 0):

In Adapter add some method for dynamic updating the views.

```
public void addSome(String element)
{

   //Update your arraylist here

   notifyDateSetChanged();//This is used to refresh adapter.

}
```

Or refer the Lazy-loading examples in stackoverflow.

Comment: Yea I get that but my doubt is that I'm parsing the xml data into a string array. How can I add this string array to the adapter?

Comment: Try with arraylist! it is very easy,because it takes dynamic allocation.