# Implement Endless scroll on ListView

Tags: android, listview

I would like to implement endless scroll on an android ListView component, that will add new items to the bottom of the listview when scrolled to the last element in the list.

Answer (score 35):

implement the onscrolllistener()

```
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    this.currentFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
    this.currentVisibleItemCount = visibleItemCount;
}

public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    this.currentScrollState = scrollState;
    this.isScrollCompleted();
 }

private void isScrollCompleted() {
    if (this.currentVisibleItemCount > 0 && this.currentScrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
        /*** In this way I detect if there's been a scroll which has completed ***/
        /*** do the work for load more date! ***/
        if(!isLoading){
             isLoading = true;
             loadMoreDAta();
        }
    }
}
```

as you implement and add this listener to your listview this will detect for the end of listview as scroll position was at end of list just get more data. And during the loading data you need one flag to load data at once when the scroll position goes to end. So if data is loading and during that time you scroll up then scroll down then it will not get more data for dupplication.

Comment: hai, can u tell me how to add data when the scroll reaches to the bottom in gridview .in page wise.i am trying this for 2 weeks.can u help me

Comment: add data into your list or arraylist or array which you have pass to your adapter for the gridview and call the notifyDataSetChanged() of adapter after data added to refresh gridview.

Comment: to avoid the isScrollCompleted being called multiple times i have adjusted the method to use a threshold, i.e. only if that number of items are visible.

public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        this.currentScrollState = scrollState;

        if ((jobAdapter.getCount() - (currentFirstVisibleItem + currentVisibleItemCount)) <= threshold) {
            this.isScrollCompleted();
        }
    }

Comment: @Pratik  how to load data from server once i reach to the end of list ?

Comment: @Erum I have write loadMoreDAta(); in isScrollCompleted() you need to create this method and get the data from server. You just need to manage the pagination with passing param in your API.

Comment: @Pratik  i have written method that will bring data from server but i m not getting how to pass pagination ?? i  m dealing like this first bring only 6 items then again 6+6 then again 6+6+6 how will i do this ? /

Comment: @Erum I don't know your were passing any param or not in your api but You need to pass 1 param as Page like Page = 1 for first time, on next call Page = 2 and so on... Now at your server side script get that Page and as per that get that value from table.

Comment: @Pratik  if i have to show only 5 data in gridview then will i  load only 5 data from server by passing limit to server -http://abccom/api/UserAll/param/345/login_id/343/page/1/limit/10000

Answer (score 9):

Try with [OnScrollListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html) Just add the items to your `ListView` in your

```
public void onScroll(AbsListView view,
    int firstVisible, int visibleCount, int totalCount) {

    // Add the items

    }
}
```

And, setting your `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` will display the added items in your `ListView` Here i give you some example that how to integrate the `onScrollListener` with your ListView

1. [Android Endless List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1080811/940096)
2. [Endless Scrolling Listview](http://benjii.me/2010/08/endless-scrolling-listview-in-android/)
3. [Endless ListView](http://andytsui.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/tutorial-infinite-scroll-endless-list-view-with-android-binding/)