# i want grid view with loading by scroll i have image fetch from sever but i want only 10 images view other can load when scrolling grid view

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-gridview, android-gridlayout

```
public class NewMovie extends Activity {
GridView lv;
Vibrator vibrator;
SimpleAdapter adapter;
Button b;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i("Category", MainActivity.movie_Category);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_movie);

    vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    lv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

    // URL to the JSON data
    String strUrl = "http://vaibhavtech.com/work/android/movie_list.php?category="
            + MainActivity.movie_Category + "&sub_category=new";
    // Creating a new non-ui thread task to download json data
    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
    // Starting the download processt
    downloadTask.execute(strUrl);

    // Getting a reference to ListView of activity_main
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            vibrator.vibrate(40);
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customtoast,
                    (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_layout));
            Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
            toast.setView(view);
            toast.show();
            MainActivity.movie_Id = ((TextView) arg1
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_girdview_content_id)).getText()
                    .toString();
            Log.i("Name is", MainActivity.movie_Id);

            startActivity(new Intent(NewMovie.this, MovieDescription.class));
        }

    });

}

/** A method to download json data from url */
private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();

        // Connecting to url
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Reading data from url
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                iStream));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

        data = sb.toString();

        br.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    } finally {
        iStream.close();
    }

    return data;
}

/** AsyncTask to download json data */
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    String data = null;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        try {
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        // The parsing of the xml data is done in a non-ui thread
        ListViewLoaderTask listViewLoaderTask = new ListViewLoaderTask();

        // Start parsing xml data
        listViewLoaderTask.execute(result);

    }
}

/** AsyncTask to parse json data and load ListView */
private class ListViewLoaderTask extends
        AsyncTask<String, Void, SimpleAdapter> {

    JSONObject jObject;

    // Doing the parsing of xml data in a non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected SimpleAdapter doInBackground(String... strJson) {
        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(strJson[0]);
            MovieParser countryJsonParser = new MovieParser();
            countryJsonParser.parse(jObject);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("JSON Exception1", e.toString());
        }

        // Instantiating json parser class
        MovieParser countryJsonParser = new MovieParser();

        // A list object to store the parsed countries list
        List<HashMap<String, Object>> countries = null;

        try {
            // Getting the parsed data as a List construct
            countries = countryJsonParser.parse(jObject);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
        }

        // Keys used in Hashmap
        String[] from = { "image", "id", "year", "duration", "name" };

        // Ids of views in listview_layout
        // int[] to = {
        // R.id.iv_radio_data_image,R.id.tv_radio_data_id,R.id.tv_radio_data_like,R.id.tv_radio_data_rating,R.id.tv_radio_data_listner,R.id.tv_radio_data_radio_url,R.id.tv_radio_data_name};
        int[] to = { R.id.iv_girdview_content_image,
                R.id.tv_girdview_content_id, R.id.tv_girdview_content_like,
                R.id.tv_girdview_content_listner,
                R.id.tv_girdview_content_name };
        // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
        // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), countries,
                R.layout.grid_view_content, from, to);

        return adapter;
        // lv.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
    }

    /** Invoked by the Android on "doInBackground" is executed */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(SimpleAdapter adapter) {

        // Setting adapter for the listview
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter
                    .getItem(i);
            String imgUrl = (String) hm.get("flag_path");
            ImageLoaderTask imageLoaderTask = new ImageLoaderTask();

            HashMap<String, Object> hmDownload = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            hm.put("flag_path", imgUrl);
            hm.put("position", i);

            // Starting ImageLoaderTask to download and populate image in
            // the listview
            imageLoaderTask.execute(hm);

        }

        // }

    }

    /** AsyncTask to download and load an image in ListView */
    private class ImageLoaderTask
            extends
            AsyncTask<HashMap<String, Object>, Void, HashMap<String, Object>> {

        @Override
        protected HashMap<String, Object> doInBackground(
                HashMap<String, Object>... hm) {

            InputStream iStream = null;
            String imgUrl = (String) hm[0].get("flag_path");
            int position = (Integer) hm[0].get("position");

            URL url;
            try {
                url = new URL(imgUrl);

                // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();

                // Connecting to url
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Reading data from url
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                // Getting Caching directory
                File cacheDirectory = getBaseContext().getCacheDir();

                // Temporary file to store the downloaded image
                File tmpFile = new File(cacheDirectory.getPath() + "/wpta_"
                        + position + ".png");

                // The FileOutputStream to the temporary file
                FileOutputStream fOutStream = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

                // Creating a bitmap from the downloaded inputstream
                Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream);

                // Writing the bitmap to the temporary file as png file
                b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOutStream);

                // Flush the FileOutputStream
                fOutStream.flush();

                // Close the FileOutputStream
                fOutStream.close();

                // Create a hashmap object to store image path and its
                // position in the listview
                HashMap<String, Object> hmBitmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                // Storing the path to the temporary image file
                hmBitmap.put("image", tmpFile.getPath());

                // Storing the position of the image in the listview
                hmBitmap.put("position", position);

                // Returning the HashMap object containing the image path
                // and position
                return hmBitmap;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, Object> result) {
            // Getting the path to the downloaded image
            String path = (String) result.get("image");

            // Getting the position of the downloaded image
            int position = (Integer) result.get("position");

            // Getting adapter of the listview
            adapter = (SimpleAdapter) lv.getAdapter();

            // Getting the hashmap object at the specified position of the
            // listview
            HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter
                    .getItem(position);

            // Overwriting the existing path in the adapter
            hm.put("image", path);

            // lv.invalidateViews();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    }

}
```

---------***************************************-------------------------------------------

PLZ help i found this ans from loag time i want loading more image from server when scrolling like facebook app style. above my code plz help me.

Comment: i did not worked on this, this may help you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583419/android-listview-automatically-load-more-data-when-scroll-to-the-bottom

Comment: @SathishKumar its ok but you known why my app unfortunately app stop when time some image load.

Comment: post your logcat then only i can identify what goes wrong

Comment: @SathishKumar plz help and give me idea about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676978/how-can-in-my-audio-player-app-i-am-play-song-and-button-of-play-and-pause-show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Benji helped me here.

```
public class EndlessScrollListener implements OnScrollListener {

    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    private int currentPage = 0;
    private int previousTotal = 0;
    private boolean loading = true;

    public EndlessScrollListener() {
    }
    public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold) {
        this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if (loading) {
            if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                loading = false;
                previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                currentPage++;
            }
        }
        if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
            // I load the next page of gigs using a background task,
            // but you can call any function here.
            new LoadGigsTask().execute(currentPage + 1);
            loading = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    }
}
```

Check this [out](http://benjii.me/2010/08/endless-scrolling-listview-in-android/)

Comment: Replace this line `mImageLoader.displayImage(        "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS2IhCj9av5PIv4ZThNnLCirOSPktnXqIE8yvg9j41hLBH31keM"        holder.imgMovie);`  with `mImageLoader.displayImage(   "http://vaibhavtech.com/work/android/admin/upload/"        + mDemoDataAl.get(position).getmDemoPoster(),     holder.imgMovie);`  This is at line # 200. And i can't help you with loading data while scroll without proper information.

Comment: hey plz help again in movie app yow gave me endless listner in NewMovie.java file but one problem in there after the scroll gridview previous image replace by below images and again scroll up its again load i want its load one time and never  be change on scroll.

Comment: Ok my JSON has 10000 images, so how can I stop the images initially, that only 10 images must show ? And when I'll scroll then next 10 images must be show.

Comment: @AmitJayaswal It is not a good practice to load 10000 images in a json. It will take more time to parse / respond and lag in UI too. The above answer is not for your requirement. You can implement onScrollListener and customize your need.

Comment: Ok @RethinavelPillai then I'll get first 10 images from JSON, and in onScroll() I'll call the same JSON with increment the counter, so next time I'll get the current 10 + next 10 images. Is it right way ? Because with the help of this way my app will not get too much load.

Comment: @AmitJayaswal : Yup, You can do the same.

Comment: @RethinavelPillai  can u tell me  how u mange to download from server ?