# Android : Loading huge data in CursorAdapter through a single query hangs the UI

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursoradapter

I have a listView associated with a CursorAdapter than can have more than 5k of rows. I am using CursorLoader for the same and it hangs the UI for a long time. I have gone through similar posts that are already present on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13723567/android-handling-very-large-data-sets-in-contentprovider-to-avoid-memory-limits) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873869/android-how-to-query-huge-database-in-android-cursor-size-is-limited-to-1mb).

I do understand that fetching such a big data and loading it on the UI is very huge to process and load into memory. Saying this, I still need to get it in my adapter.

I have considered using [Scrolling Cursor](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ScrollingCursor) but the other problem that I would go through is while implementing Alphabetical Indexing similar to what Android Contacts app have and which stops me from updating the cursor part-wise

Also, my query makes use of a left-outer join along with an Order by clause

I am hoping there might be some way of doing this. It has already been done in the Android basic apps such as Contacts, Music and so on.

Comment: I think you have to implement paging. Dont load all data altogether, but bring it with paging, I mean when you reach at last record get another 10 records and display them. Its very easy way to load and display. No other way to develop this I think vaidehi.

Comment: Thank You Pratik for the prompt reply, but my requirement isn't to page among the items. I need to show it altogether in a single view

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52222/discussion-between-vaidehi-and-pratik join this vaidehi