# How to limit list items display in ListView by 10 and next 10after clicking next button

Tags: android, android-listview, android-button

i have a listview with 100 items and i want to display first 10 items and on click of next button i have to display next 10 ie.,from 11 to 20, i have the code for getting first 10 items

```
public int getCount() {
        return 10;
    }
```

but how to get next 10 items alone and so on.
any idea

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080811/android-endless-list http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-listview-with-load-more-button/

Comment: i have to use only one listview and also it has to display the next 19 alone not from 1 to 10

Comment: Call set adapter again with the new arraylist that contains next set of data.

Comment: @anukool how do i get the next 10 items in that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to do this is,

1) Don't populate your ArrayList with all the data. Instead keep them in a separate ArrayList (`al1`) and use an ArrayList (`al2`) with max 10 values to use with your BaseAdapter.

2) Initially,

- al2 = al1[0] to al1[9]
- BaseAdatper(context, data)

3) Keep the BaseAdapter as it is but change

```
 @Override
 public int getCount() {
 return 10;
}
```

to

```
 @Override
 public int getCount() {
 return data.size();
}
```

It's not a must but it's good practice. Now you'll be showing only 10 items cause that's all you are passing to the adapter. Also write a public function in your extended BaseAdatper class to set the `data` variable.

4) On the next button click event get the next 10 items from `al1` and assign to `al2`. Use the public function you wrote to over write `data` with `al2`.

5) [BaseAdapter has a method called notifyDataSetChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) , call it. What this does is tell the adapter to refresh from top to bottom. Since you have `data` over written with new data when the refresh occurs you'll be seeing the new data. That's it.

I don't think it'll be difficult for you to come up with a way to keep track from which index to which in `al1` you're currently displaying. :)

Comment: how to get al2 = al1[0] to al1[9] because im using like this  arraylist of  products ie.,  ArrayList<Product> array_sort

Comment: I'm not sure of what you're asking. Are you asking how to get values from - to an index or how to keep track of  the next index you should grab data from `al1` ?

Comment: `// class level variable
currIndex = 0;

onNextButtonClick() {
 for(var i = currIndex;  i < 10; i++) {
  // have a condition to check al1.get(i) is not going out of bounds
  al2.add(al1.get(i));  
  currIndex++;
 }
}`

Comment: thanks logic is corect but since im using ArrayList<Product> i m getting some error

Comment: @JanithaR can u give me some example for the above process. Am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you have 100 items, then just take the first 10 items for your adapter, and when the user presses next, get the next 10, and so on.

EDIT: On request for code, I can provide a simple example on how to do pagination.

```
int totalItems = 100;
int currentPage = 0;
int pageSize = 10;
int numPages = (int) Math.ceil((float) totalItems/pageSize);

ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>(totalItems);

List<String> page = items.subList(currentPage, pageSize);
```

Looking at the example above, given the number of items and the desired page size you can calculate how many pages you need to display, you can then select a sub list from your ArrayList. Each time the user presses next, increment the currentPage and refresh the adapter with the a new sub list.

Comment: Ok, but you need to first post what code you have, are you using an array list or something else for your data source?

Comment: i am using arraylist to store the data and to display and slao using adapter class which extends BaseAdapter

Comment: this code generating exception if there is 12 record after 
for (int i = 0; i <numPages ; i++) {
                    int output = i+1;
                    List<ModelDetail> splitData =  arrayDetail.subList(currentPage, pageSize);
                    myModel.add(splitData);
                }