# How to get an endless ListView, like the market's one?

Tags: android, listview, dynamic

I'll receive my data from a webpage and i'll use Gson library and AsyncTask.

What is the best way to push the new elements to the list?
I thought to save a list containing the data as field of the activity, and when an update is received call notifyDataSetChanged().

But in this way, the whole list will be refreshed, will it?

Comment: Probably copy from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080811/android-endless-list/1082523#1082523).
Hope It helped.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you are looking for:

https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless