# Android - How to make an infinite Scroll View

Tags: android, uiscrollview, scrollview, custom-scrolling

I am trying to make a background that the user can scroll through infinitely (i.e scroll never ends).
I have added a bunch of image views to the scroll view in XML, however, I am having trouble finding a way to make sure that the background never runs out.
When the user reaches the end, ideally the top images should automatically relocate to below the view so that there is always more to scroll.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/tp_texture_long"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/tp_texture_long"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/tp_texture_long"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/tp_texture_long"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/tp_texture_long"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Use nestedscrollview

Comment: Can you please post an answer on how to do that and if it works i can mark as correct, never used it before

Comment: Why do you want to scroll down unfinitely? You may put images in a recyclerview and repeat images. If you want to scroll down unfinitely, what about your memory usage?

Comment: The plan was to remove images above the threshold when you scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19469147/4866695) answer. But you should use a [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) instead of `ListView`.