# ListView onScroll add more items

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-asynctask

```
    private class getArticles extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String url;

    getArticles(String paramUrl) {
        this.url = paramUrl;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(App.this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Učitavanje artikala...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        arraylist = new ArrayList<>();

        try {

            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Elements els = document.select("ul.category3 > li");

            for (Element el : els) {

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

                Elements slika = el.select("div.category3-image > a > img");
                Elements naslov = el.select("div.category3-text > a.main-headline");
                Element datum_noformat = el.select("div.category3-text > div.headlines-info > ul.headlines-info > li").first();
                Element datum = datum_noformat.html(datum_noformat.html().replaceAll("Posted ", ""));
                Elements desc = el.select("div.category3-text > p");
                Elements link = el.select("div.category3-text > a.main-headline");
                Element br_kom = el.select("div.category3-text > div.headlines-info > ul.headlines-info > li.comments-icon").first();

                map.put("naslov", naslov.text());
                map.put("datum", datum.text());
                map.put("desc", desc.text());
                map.put("ikona", slika.attr("src"));
                map.put("link", link.attr("abs:href"));
                map.put("brkom", br_kom.text());
                arraylist.add(map);


            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        adapter = new ArtikliAdapter(App.this, arraylist);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

I searched for a lot of codes for onlistview scrolling, but didn't know how to implement it. The problem is, when I call my asynctask, I have an url param,
like `new getArticles("http://example.com").execute();`

I want to implement an onscrolllistener, but it goes like this, my param is usually set to: `http://www.example.com/category/categoryname/`, so the second page goes like `http://www.example.com/category/categoryname/page/2/`, the third one goes `http://www.example.com/category/categoryname/page/3/` and so on. Each page has got 7 items that need to be parsed.

How could I implement onscrolllistener, because of the url param?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what you'd like to do? I'm guessing that you want to implement an `OnScrollListener` that will kick off your `AsyncTask` to go fetch more documents when the user gets to the bottom of the page, correct? Are these new documents going to be appended to the bottom of your `ListView`?

Comment: @MarkCramer Yes, I want to add those items (the next page) when the user gets to the bottom.

Comment: You should take a look at `RecyclerView`. Google for `RecyclerView` endless list, or something.
Here's a hit: http://android-pratap.blogspot.ro/2015/01/endless-recyclerview-onscrolllistener.html

And have a counter inside your scroller, so each time you hit the end of your results, you increase your counter... so you know on which page you are.

Comment: Try this [link](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews).

Comment: I'm deleting my post because @avinash found a better answer. Wrapping your `ListView` in a `ScrollView` would work, but your `ListView` already supports `OnScrollListener` so that's an easier way to go.

Comment: @avinash Having some problems, could we discuss it somewhere?

Comment: Update the question with what you've got and we'll see how we can help. The link @avinash gave you is what you need, however.

Comment: Sure, as @ Mark Cramer said update your question we will see how could we help. This is the best place to discuss.

Comment: You should pick the right answer and award the points.

Answer (score 13):

Base on this [link](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews), I have written following solution to add elements ( 30 elements at a time, i.e page size = 30) to listview asynchronously.

Create a class named EndlessListView as follows:

```
public class EndlessListView extends ListView implements OnScrollListener {

private View footer;
private boolean isLoading;
private EndlessListener listener;// listner
private EndlessAdapter endlessAdapter;// adapter.

private int maxNoOfElement;

public EndlessListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.setOnScrollListener(this);
}

public EndlessListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.setOnScrollListener(this);
}

public EndlessListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.setOnScrollListener(this);
}

public void setListener(EndlessListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

    if (getAdapter() == null)
        return;

    if (getAdapter().getCount() == 0 || getAdapter().getCount() <= 5)
        return;

    int l = visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItem;
    if (l >= totalItemCount && !isLoading) {
        // It is time to add new data. We call the listener
        Log.e("LOAD", "DATA");
        isLoading = true;
        listener.loadData();

    }
}

public void setMaxElemnt(int maxNoOfElement) {
    this.maxNoOfElement = maxNoOfElement;
}

@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
}

public void setLoadingView(int resId) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) super.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    footer = (View) inflater.inflate(resId, null);
    this.addFooterView(footer);
}

public void setAdapter(EndlessAdapter adapter) {
    super.setAdapter(adapter);
    this.endlessAdapter = adapter;

}

public void addNewData(List<Integer> data) {
    endlessAdapter.setData(data);
    endlessAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    isLoading = false;
}

public static interface EndlessListener {
    public void loadData();

}

 }
```

After this we have to create the adapter for it,called

EndlessAdapter

```
public class EndlessAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private List<Integer> mIntegers;
private Context context;

public EndlessAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public void setData(List<Integer> mIntegers) {
    this.mIntegers = mIntegers;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    if (mIntegers == null)
        return 0;
    return mIntegers.size();
}

@Override
public Integer getItem(int index) {

    if (mIntegers == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return mIntegers.get(index);
    }
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

class ViewHolder {
    TextView textView;
}

@Override
public View getView(int index, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = ((LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
                .inflate(R.layout.rows, viewGroup, false);
        holder.textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mtext);
        view.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    holder.textView.setText(getItem(index) + "");
    return view;
}

   }
```

Now in xml of the activity we could use EndlessListView(in com.example.stackoverflow package) as follows :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.example.stackoverflow.EndlessListView
    android:id="@+id/endlessListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

After this step we need to make following change in the MainActivity

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements EndlessListener {
private EndlessAdapter adapter;
private EndlessListView endlessListView;
private List<Integer> data;
private int gStartIndex = 30;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    endlessListView = (EndlessListView) findViewById(R.id.endlessListView);
    adapter = new EndlessAdapter(this);
    data = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    endlessListView.setLoadingView(R.layout.footer);
    // endlessListView.showFooter();
    endlessListView.setListener(this);
    endlessListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    gStartIndex = 0;
    fillData(gStartIndex);
}

private void fillData(int startIndex) {

    new AsyncLoadData().execute(startIndex);

}

@Override
public void loadData() {

    fillData(gStartIndex);

}

private class AsyncLoadData extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        int gendIndex = params[0] + 30;
        gStartIndex = gendIndex;
        /***
         * Here you could add your n/w code. To simulate the n/w comm. i am
         * adding elements to list and making it sleep for few sec.
         * */
        for (int i = params[0]; i < gendIndex; i++) {
            publishProgress(i);

        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        data.add(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        endlessListView.addNewData(data);
    }
}

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This custom [ScrollListView](https://gist.github.com/marteinn/3757968) that I just found has `OnBottomReachedListener` which you can implement from your `Activity` or `Fragment` and receive events when user hits the bottom of the page. You would also need to track the current page and when bottom is hit to download the next page. The latest data should be added to your existing `ArrayList` and you should call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter so `ListView` can render the new data. You don't have to create new adapter, you just need to update the data source which is your `ArrayList`.

If you support orientation change you would must to save in `onSaveInstanceState()` your current page number so when `Activity` or `Fragment` is recreated it can continue from correct page. And you would have to keep the `ArrayList` data source safe of configuration changes because you don't want to downloaded it again. I would suggest using the `Fragment` with `setRetainInstance()` set to `true` to persist `ArrayList`.

Here is my custom code for keeping data around using RetainFragment:

```
/**
 * A simple non-UI Fragment that stores a single Object
 * and is retained over configuration changes.
 */
public class RetainFragment<E extends Object> extends Fragment {

    /** Object for retaining. */
    private E mObject;

    /**
     * Empty constructor as per the Fragment documentation
     */
    public RetainFragment() {}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Make sure this Fragment is retained over a configuration change
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    /**
     * Store a single object in this Fragment.
     *
     * @param object The object to store
     */
    public void setObject(E object) {
        mObject = object;
    }

    /**
     * Get the stored object.
     *
     * @return The stored object
     */
    public E getObject() {
        return mObject;
    }
}
```

Example of `RetainFragment` usage in your `Activity`:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
mRetainFragment = (RetainFragment<ArrayList>) fm.findFragmentByTag(RETAIN_FRAG);
if (mRetainFragment == null) {
    mRetainFragment = new RetainFragment<>();
    mRetainFragment.setObject(new ArrayList());
    fm.beginTransaction().add(mRetainFragment, RETAIN_FRAG).commit();
}

ArrayList yourArrayList = mRetainFragment.getObject();
// Now your ArrayList is saved accrossed configuration changes
```

Answer (score 1):

here what you want fist add onscrolllistner to listview

```
      boolean loading_flage = false;

                                    yourlistview.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onScrollStateChanged(
                                                AbsListView view,
                                                int scrollState) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onScroll(AbsListView view,
                                                int firstVisibleItem,
                                                int visibleItemCount,
                                                int totalItemCount) {

                                            final int lastItem = firstVisibleItem
                                                    + visibleItemCount;

                                            if ((lastItem == totalItemCount)
                                                    & loading_flage == false) {

//this to prevent the list to make more than one request in time
                                                loading_flage = true;
    //you can put the index for your next page here
                                                loadMore(int page);

                                            }

                                        }
                                    });
```

and then in loading more after loading the page set the  loading with false and parse the data add it to the data that you aleardy have

```
                      //notify the adapter
                     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                      loading_flage = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve by adding the scrolllistener on listview and check condition if list last visible item is last in ArrayList then call the asynctask with incremented page number and update the listview,mean while add the view on listview and after getting the result from server remove the loading more view from the listview like this -
AndroidListViewLoadMoreActivity.java

```
public class AndroidListViewLoadMoreActivity extends Activity {

 ArrayList<Country> countryList;
 MyCustomAdapter dataAdapter = null;
 int page = 0;
 boolean loadingMore = false;
 View loadMoreView;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

  loadMoreView = ((LayoutInflater)this
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
    .inflate(R.layout.loadmore, null, false);
  listView.addFooterView(loadMoreView);

  //create an ArrayAdaptar from the String Array
  countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();
  dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this,
    R.layout.country_info, countryList);
  listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

  //enables filtering for the contents of the given ListView
  listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
     int position, long id) {
    // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
    Country country = (Country) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
      country.getCode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
  });

  listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener(){

   @Override
   public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {}

   @Override
   public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
     int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

   int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;    
   if((lastInScreen == totalItemCount) && !(loadingMore)){     
    String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/CountryWebService" + 
     "/CountryServlet";
    grabURL(url); 
   }
   }
  });

  String url = "http://example.com";
  grabURL(url); 

 }

 public void grabURL(String url) {
  Log.v("Android Spinner JSON Data Activity", url);
  new GrabURL().execute(url);
 }

 private class GrabURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
  private static final int REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT = 3 * 1000;
  private static final int WAIT_TIMEOUT = 30 * 1000;
  private final HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  final HttpParams params = httpclient.getParams();
  HttpResponse response;
  private String content =  null;
  private boolean error = false;
  private ProgressDialog dialog = 
   new ProgressDialog(AndroidListViewLoadMoreActivity.this);

  protected void onPreExecute() {
   dialog.setMessage("Getting your data... Please wait...");
   dialog.show();
  }

  protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

   String URL = null;
   loadingMore = true;

   try {

   URL = urls[0];
   HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT);
   HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, WAIT_TIMEOUT);
   ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, WAIT_TIMEOUT);

   HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);

   //add name value pair for the country code
   List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("page",String.valueOf(page)));

   httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs)); 
   response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
    if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
     ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
     out.close();
     content = out.toString();
    } else{
     //Closes the connection.
     Log.w("HTTP1:",statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
     response.getEntity().getContent().close();
     throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
    }
   } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    Log.w("HTTP2:",e );
    content = e.getMessage();
    error = true;
    cancel(true);
   } catch (IOException e) {
    Log.w("HTTP3:",e );
    content = e.getMessage();
    error = true;
    cancel(true);
   }catch (Exception e) {
    Log.w("HTTP4:",e );
    content = e.getMessage();
    error = true;
    cancel(true);
   }

   return content;
  }

  protected void onCancelled() {
   dialog.dismiss();
   Toast toast = Toast.makeText(AndroidListViewLoadMoreActivity.this, 
     "Error connecting to Server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
   toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 25, 400);
   toast.show();

  }

  protected void onPostExecute(String content) {
   dialog.dismiss();
   Toast toast;
   if (error) {
    toast = Toast.makeText(AndroidListViewLoadMoreActivity.this, 
      content, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 25, 400);
    toast.show();
   } else {
    displayCountryList(content);
   }
  }

 }

 private void displayCountryList(String response){

  JSONObject responseObj = null; 

  try {

   Gson gson = new Gson();
   responseObj = new JSONObject(response); 
   JSONArray countryListObj = responseObj.getJSONArray("countryList");

   //countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();
   if(countryListObj.length() == 0){
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listView.removeFooterView(loadMoreView);
   }
   else {
    for (int i=0; i<countryListObj.length(); i++){
    //get the country information JSON object
    String countryInfo = countryListObj.getJSONObject(i).toString();
    //create java object from the JSON object
    Country country = gson.fromJson(countryInfo, Country.class);
    //add to country array list
    countryList.add(country);
    dataAdapter.add(country);
    }
         page++;
    dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    loadingMore = false;
   }

  } catch (JSONException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

 }
```

}

Make MyCustomAdapter.java as adapter

```
private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Country> {

  private ArrayList<Country> countryList;

  public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, 
    ArrayList<Country> countryList) {
   super(context, textViewResourceId, countryList);
   this.countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();
   this.countryList.addAll(countryList);
  }

  private class ViewHolder {
   TextView code;
   TextView name;
   TextView continent;
   TextView region;
  }

  public void add(Country country){
   Log.v("AddView", country.getCode());
   this.countryList.add(country);
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   ViewHolder holder = null;
   Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));
   if (convertView == null) {

   LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(
     Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.country_info, null);

   holder = new ViewHolder();
   holder.code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);
   holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
   holder.continent = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.continent);
   holder.region = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.region);

   convertView.setTag(holder);

   } else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
   }

   Country country = this.countryList.get(position);
   holder.code.setText(country.getCode());
   holder.name.setText(country.getName());
   holder.continent.setText(country.getContinent());
   holder.region.setText(country.getRegion());

   return convertView;

  }

 }
}
```

Create Country.Java as pojo -

```
public class Country {

 String code = null;
 String name = null;
 String continent = null;
 String region = null;
 Double lifeExpectancy = null;
 Double gnp = null;
 Double surfaceArea = null;
 int population = 0;

 public String getCode() {
  return code;
 }
 public void setCode(String code) {
  this.code = code;
 }
 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }
 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }
 public String getContinent() {
  return continent;
 }
 public void setContinent(String continent) {
  this.continent = continent;
 }
 public String getRegion() {
  return region;
 }
 public void setRegion(String region) {
  this.region = region;
 }
 public Double getLifeExpectancy() {
  return lifeExpectancy;
 }
 public void setLifeExpectancy(Double lifeExpectancy) {
  this.lifeExpectancy = lifeExpectancy;
 }
 public Double getGnp() {
  return gnp;
 }
 public void setGnp(Double gnp) {
  this.gnp = gnp;
 }
 public Double getSurfaceArea() {
  return surfaceArea;
 }
 public void setSurfaceArea(Double surfaceArea) {
  this.surfaceArea = surfaceArea;
 }
 public int getPopulation() {
  return population;
 }
 public void setPopulation(int population) {
  this.population = population;
 }

}
```

Create main.xml for main layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">

 <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="10dp"
  android:text="@string/some_text" android:textSize="20sp" />

 <ListView android:id="@+id/listView1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Create country_info.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Code: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Name: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="Continent: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="Region: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/continent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/region"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/continent"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/code"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Footer View Text - loadmore.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Loading more data..."/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Don't forget to mention internet permission with -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a OnScrollListener method like this:

```
private OnScrollListener onScrollListener() {
    return new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            int threshold = 1;
            int count = listView.getCount();

            if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                if (listView.getLastVisiblePosition() >= count - threshold && pageCount < 2) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "loading more data");
                    // Execute LoadMoreDataTask AsyncTask
                    //It reached ListView bottom
                    getDataFromUrl(url_page2);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount,
                int totalItemCount) {
        }

    };
}
```

set List View scroll listener by `listView.setOnScrollListener(onScrollListener());`

I have a full tutorial post [HERE](http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/03/android-listview-dynamically-load-more.html)! You can visit it!