# How to implement Endless Adapter into my listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scrollview, endlessadapter

I wanted to ask, how can I implement pagination (like this one : https://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/ ) into my list view ? 
Can someone help pls, where do I start ?

Here is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    // Declare Variables
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ListView listview;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;

    static String ID = "id";
    static String TITLE = "title";
    static String S_DESC = "s_desc";
    static String IMG = "img";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        // Get the view from listview_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);
        // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
        new DownloadJSON().execute();

        //test

        //end test


    }





    // DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android JSON Parse Tutorial");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show(); 
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                    .getJSONfromURL(" getting data from my url");


            try {
                // Locate the array name in JSON
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("data");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Retrive JSON Objects
                    map.put("id", jsonobject.getString("id"));
                    map.put("title", jsonobject.getString("title"));
                    map.put("s_desc", jsonobject.getString("s_desc"));
                    map.put("img", jsonobject.getString("img"));
                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        /* Test bt */

        /* here end */



        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist);

            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.action_share) {
            sharePost();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    protected void sharePost() {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, S_DESC);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getString(R.string.share_chooser_title)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

follo this tutorial on github,this ll help you...

https://github.com/shontauro/android-pulltorefresh-and-loadmore

Answer (score 0):

5 years later and the Android world uses maybe more of RecyclerViews. If you are still interested in endless loading for listviews however, you can check out [this](https://github.com/gbenroscience/EndlessAdapter) library which I published.

Also, check out this stackoverflow answer which I posted [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56653275/1845404)