# Regarding Pagination in Android

Tags: android, pagination

I have implemented on Listview. And What i want is to implement pagination in it . when i reach the end of the listview(20 items per page) it should refresh and new contents should be loaded. I dont know how ... Could anyone please tell me.

```
private static ListView mList;
```

in Oncreate i have added

```
mList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.mypclist);
```

Once it reaches the first 20 items in the listview , then the list should refresh and add new items... Please help me

Comment: Refer this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080811/android-endless-list/1082523#1082523

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must create a scroll listener and add it to your listview.

```
yourListView.setOnScrollListener(this);
```

In the onScroll implementation

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView lw, final int firstVisibleItem,
             final int visibleItemCount, final int totalItemCount) {

    switch(lw.getId()) {
       case android.R.id.list:     
            final int lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
            if (lastItem == totalItemCount) {
                if(preLast != lastItem){ //to avoid multiple calls for last item
                    loadNextItems();
                    preLast = lastItem;
                }
            }
        }
    }


private void loadNextItems() {
    // Load your next items
    // Modify your adapter list and call adapter.notifyDataSetChange()
}
```

Comment: Hi,I have tried above. But when the list refreshed for the second time the previous contents are overwrited. how to avoid this?

Comment: put your loadNextItems code in your question, there must be a problem in it