# How to store data efficiently for an ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, arrays, memory, android-arrayadapter

I want to make a simple **AutoCompleteTextview** where there will be auto suggestion of mobile numbers while user typing.
I did something like following

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        String dummyNumbers[] = {"01912953698","01912963698","01912963798","01712963698",
            "01716581932","01716581931","01716582931","01837338077","01837338078"};

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            AutoCompleteTextView edittext = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.auto_suggestion);
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,dummyNumbers);
            edittext.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

It works fine.

Now my question is if i have a database of 1 millions of mobile number data and  I query those numbers then store them to my '**dummyNumbers**' array variable, will it be efficient?

*In common sense, storing 1 millions data in an array at runtime obviously is high memory consumption.*

Is there any efficient way of what I wanting to do or storing 1M data and making operation on them won't create any problem (android will somehow handle that in background).

Comment: i think asynctask will do the job for you

Comment: @GiannisMpountouridis I don't think so. I might be wrong. May you elaborate?

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080811/android-endless-list will help for u